# ACL Question. access-list permit ip any any

Tags: cisco, acl

so quick question, in the ACL bellow, Would "permit ip any any" allow ICMP packet to traverse the router? Or is "permit ip any any" in the ACL only referring to allowing any layer 3 address from traversing the router and since there is not a specific ACL for ICMP packets it will deny (Implicit Deny).

```
access-list 102 permit tcp any any eq ftp
access-list 102 permit tcp any any eq ftp-data
access-list 102 deny tcp any any eq telnet
access-list 102 deny icmp any any echo-reply
access-list 102 permit ip any any
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Referring to IP in an access list refers to all IP based protocols. You have denied echo replies but all other messages as ICMP redirect, time exceeded, fragmentation needed, echo would be allowed through.

Other IP based protocols such as OSPF would also be allowed to pass through with your ACL.